# eclipse plugin classpath issue

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, eclipse-plugin

Created multimodule maven project where folder structure is as below,

```
|-ProjectA
  |-projectB
  |-projectC
  |-projectD
```

Created jar of ProjectA using maven shade and AppendingTransformer to include spring handlers,Schema.(Project B uses spring 3.0.7.RELEASE)

Then added this ProjectA jar in eclipse plugin project and build path.
One of the eclipse project calls ProjectB.method(); which loads configuration file as,

```
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath*:META-INF/myfolder/plugin.xml");
```

This plugin.xml has

```
 <context:component-scan base-package="mysamplefolderpath" />
```

Problem occurs when it's starts scanning base package in all the jars which are in classpath of eclipse plugin project (eclipse plugin project uses spring 3.0.5.RELEASE).

How can I restrict that base package scan in classpath of ProjectA only?

Answer (score 0):

I got solution. Created shaded jar so plugin refers the required jars in that class path only. Resolved conflict between other jars(having different versions).